# PHP form with file upload and send to email

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have a php form to send the input to my email.

in my HTML file i have this option to upload files:

```
<label class="nobg" for="uploaded_file">test</label> 
<input class="nobg" type="file" name="uploaded_file" />
```

and then in my send_form_email.php file these lines, i got from internet:

```
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], '/uploads'.$file['name']) );
  {print '<p> The file has been successfully uploaded </p>';}
```

after i submit the form "**success**" message is shown:

> The file has been successfully uploaded

and then some errors about failed to open stream: Permission denied to move the file to /uploads.
And then this one:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpk3HgFc' to '/uploads' in ****

i don't know what i did wrong?

thanks.

Comment: My recomendation would be to use MAMP instead of XAMPP on a mac - the error itself seems to be a permission problem.

Comment: Do you created the folder "uploads" before?

Comment: Well the 'Permission denied' is a give away. Clearly your php code can't / is allowed to move the upload. Be sure to unhook the file before trying to move it.

Comment: `/uploads` would refer to a directory on the filesystem root.

Comment: @mario i have the map /uploads in the same place as the other files?

Comment: Well if you want to refer to a folder inside the current folder, that would be `uploads` (or more explicitly, `./uploads`), and not `/uploads`. As mario said, the leading slash would mean it is in the root directory. Go read up on the basics of absolute and relative paths.

Comment: PD of [cannot upload images through php in XAMPP (Mac)](//stackoverflow.com/q/31224741) and [PHP: move\_uploaded\_file() failed to open stream: No such file or directory](//stackoverflow.com/q/10951334) or [PHP: Saving files with PHP to different root directory?](//stackoverflow.com/q/748915) etc.